# Getting "it" does not name a type when trying to iterate in vector, how to fix it?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When I'm running the code, it gives me an error: 'it' does not name a type, expected ';' before 'it', 'it' was not declared in this scope. But I don't see any missing ";" in my code.. how to fix it? I just followed the iterator thing from a site, nothing is different. I use dev c++.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> A[3];

int main(){
    A[0].push_back(1);
    A[1].push_back(2);
    A[1].push_back(5);
    A[2].push_back(0);
    cout<<A[0][0]<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<=2;i++){
        for(auto it = A[i].begin();it!=A[i].end();it++){
            cout<<*it<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I runned it in ideone, it works..

Comment: *"I use dev c++"* -  Ah, that would be the problem. Dev C++ is no longer maintained and comes with an out of date compiler. Try Code::Blocks instead if you are looking for a free IDE.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use raw c-style array. Use `std::array` or `std::vector`. Also, don't mix them... `vector<int> A[3];` should be `std::array<vector<int>, 3> A;`